# Cannot import .task file in Next.js + Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, tsx, mediapipe

I tried to import model.task file in App.tsx file, but it shows some errors.

I trained hand gesture recognition model and exported it to model.task file using Python. And I'm going to import it in App.tsx which is Next.js + Typescript project.

import Model from '@/utils/models/model.task';

But I'm getting an error below.

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

How to I resolve this issue? Please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've to declare .task in your webpack config

Something like this

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.task$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Take from https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I'm using Typescript and the problem was occured from App.tsx file.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the .task file inside public

And const filename= "/{filename).task"

You can't import any file directly(I don't think .task file have any export module)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).